# T-SQL - Tehnique for evaluation of boolean expression string

Tags: sql-server-2012, execute, boolean-expression

I need to populated the 'Value' field could be '0' or '1' (false or true) depending on the expression.

The following is simple data:

```
1   1 * 1 + 1   NULL
2   0 + 0       NULL
3   1 + 0 * 0   NULL
4   0 * 1       NULL
5   0 * 1 * 1   NULL
```

The 'Expression' field is of type nvarchar and contains result of conditions and boolean operators. 
So, the data above could be formated as follows:

```
1   TRUE AND TRUE OR TRUE     NULL
2   FALSE OR FALSE            NULL
3   TRUE OR FALSE AND FALSE   NULL
4   FALSE AND TRUE            NULL
5   FALSE AND TRUE AND TRUE   NULL
```

In the final, the 'Expression' field could contains AND/OR and multiple TRUE and FALSE.

What I need, as I said is to calculated the expression value - to check if it is true or false.

The whole logic is in procedure and i can build dynamic sql for each row and excecuted it, 
but in my real situation I will have hundres of rows, so creating loops and calling execute_sql for each row does not sound as good solution.

Is there any build-in function that can help me to evaluted these strings as I am not able to use cross apply with procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a user-define scalar function with input parameter the string for evaluation and return value - 0 or 1 (false or true). Now, I can do the desire cross apply...

The following are examples:

```
SELECT [dbo].[fn_XxCustom_EvaluateExpression] ('0')                 -- 0
SELECT [dbo].[fn_XxCustom_EvaluateExpression] ('1')                 -- 1
SELECT [dbo].[fn_XxCustom_EvaluateExpression] ('1*1')               -- 1
SELECT [dbo].[fn_XxCustom_EvaluateExpression] ('1+1')               -- 1
SELECT [dbo].[fn_XxCustom_EvaluateExpression] ('1*0')               -- 0
SELECT [dbo].[fn_XxCustom_EvaluateExpression] ('0+1*0*1+0*1+0')     -- 0
SELECT [dbo].[fn_XxCustom_EvaluateExpression] ('1+1+0+1*0*1+1*1+0') -- 1
```

I believe that there is a better way of doing that, maybe with Reverse Polish notation and recursive CTE, but have not got the time to try it. Anyway, this is the source code if anyone need to do something similar:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[fn_XxCustom_EvaluateExpression]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_XxCustom_EvaluateExpression]
END

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_XxCustom_EvaluateExpression]
(
    @Expression NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS TINYINT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ExpressionValue TINYINT = 0

    IF LEN(@Expression) > 0 AND @Expression IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN

        -- Checking if this is expression 
        IF CHARINDEX('+', @Expression) = 0 AND CHARINDEX('*', @Expression) = 0 
            BEGIN
                SET @ExpressionValue = CAST(@Expression AS TINYINT)
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN

                -- Checking if the expression is computed (contains both '*' and '+')
                IF CHARINDEX('+', @Expression) > 0 AND CHARINDEX('*', @Expression) > 0
                    BEGIN 

                        DECLARE @ExpressionsTable TABLE
                        (
                             ExpressionID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
                            ,Expression NVARCHAR(MAX)
                            ,ExpressionValue TINYINT
                        )

                        DECLARE @XML XML = N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@Expression, '+', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'

                        -- Populate the table with simple expressions (expression which only contains '+' or '*' is simple)
                        INSERT INTO @ExpressionsTable (Expression)
                        SELECT DISTINCT RTRIM(LTRIM(T.c.value('.', 'nvarchar(250)')))
                        FROM @xml.nodes('//r') T(c)

                        -- Creating a simple expressions with result values 
                        UPDATE @ExpressionsTable
                        SET ExpressionValue = IIF(CHARINDEX('+', Expression) = 0 AND CHARINDEX('*', Expression) = 0 , Expression, IIF(CHARINDEX('+', Expression) > 0,IIF(CHARINDEX('1', Expression) > 0, 1, 0),IIF(CHARINDEX('0', Expression) > 0, 0, 1)))

                        -- Evaluating the final expression
                        SET @ExpressionValue = IIF(CHARINDEX('1', SUBSTRING((SELECT '+' + CAST(ExpressionValue AS VARCHAR(1)) FROM @ExpressionsTable FOR XML PATH('')),2,4000)) > 0, 1, 0)

                    END
                ELSE
                -- Checking the type of the simple expression (does it contains '+' or '*')
                    BEGIN
                        SET @ExpressionValue = IIF(CHARINDEX('+', @Expression) > 0,IIF(CHARINDEX('1', @Expression) > 0, 1, 0),IIF(CHARINDEX('0', @Expression) > 0, 0, 1))
                    END
            END
    END

    RETURN @ExpressionValue

END
GO
```

Comment: Maybe try something like this: 

`declare @exp varchar(100); select @exp='1+1+0+1*0*1+1*1+0'; 

select @exp=replace(REPLACE(@exp,'+','&'),'*','&') 

select @exp;

 exec ('select '+@exp);`

Comment: @LoztInSpace I do not want to use the "exec" statement, because I will need to do this hundreds of times. That's was my initial issue, and because of this I make a scalar functions which to be executed for row. The alternative to this is to make a LOOP and in it to execute the dynamic SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

Why not evaluate it when you insert it instead of when you query it?  The cost of one bit (the result) vs the cost of parsing & executing the query is likely to be worth it.  You can do it as a trigger (yuk) or calculated column with a UDF (much nicer).

Pretty much all you'd have to do is link some dynamic SQL to some search & replace (I think).

If you've got a limited number of combinations, the other way is just a lookup on the expression (minus whitespace etc.) and the result.

Comment: Because each value (0 or 1) is result of complex select statements and checks.

Comment: You might want to update your question and sample input/output lists (especially headers).  It's now really not clear to me what you've got or what you're after.

Comment: I have managed to find the issue alone. Anyway +1 for trying to help me.